# Pinpoint/FCM returning Unregistered or expired token

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm, aws-pinpoint

I'm using Pinpoint to push notifications through FCM and I'm receiving an error back from AWS:

```
{
    "ApplicationId": "xxx",
    "RequestId": "yyy",
    "EndpointResult": {
        "5551212": {
            "DeliveryStatus": "PERMANENT_FAILURE",
            "StatusCode": 410,
            "StatusMessage": "{\"errorMessage\":\"Unregistered or expired token\",\"channelType\":\"GCM\",\"pushProviderStatusCode\":\"200\",\"pushProviderError\":\"InvalidRegistration\",\"pushProviderResponse\":\"{\\\"multicast_id\\\":752174934090126,\\\"success\\\":0,\\\"failure\\\":1,\\\"canonical_ids\\\":0,\\\"results\\\":[{\\\"error\\\":\\\"InvalidRegistration\\\"}]}\"}",
            "Address": "userID"
        }
    }
```

An oddity is that when the app is launched/loaded the Amplify.config is not calling the PushNotification.onRegister function either:

```
const amplifyConfig = {
      Auth: {
        identityPoolId: POOL_ID,
        region: 'us-east-1'
      },
      Analytics: {
        AWSPinpoint: {
              appId: APP_ID,
              region: 'us-east-1',
              mandatorySignIn: false,
              endpointId: '5551212',
              endpoint: { 
                address: 'userID',
                channelType: 'GCM',
                optOut: 'NONE'
              }
        }
      }
    }

    PushNotification.onRegister(t => console.log(`Registration token: ${t}`), onRegister && onRegister());
    PushNotification.onNotification(n => (console.log(n), onNotification && onNotification(n)));
    PushNotification.onNotificationOpened(n => (console.log(n), onNotificationOpened && onNotificationOpened(n)));
    Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig);
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Nope... still fighting this one...

Comment: any updates on this???

Comment: I ended up writing a module to retrieve the token directly.

Comment: Hi, I tried getting token from Firebase directly and once I am logged in, i am updating the endpoint with deviceToken with below configuration:
```
await Analytics.updateEndpoint({
          // address: fcmToken,
          channelType: "GCM",
          userId: uid,
          optOut: 'NONE',
        });
```
Seems like it worked and I am able to send push notification to my device. After some time like 20 mins or so if I try to push notification I am getting this error:
 "StatusCode": 410,  "StatusMessage": "{\"errorMessage\":\"Unregistered or expired token

Any idea why its coming?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Your error seems related to Invalid Registration token: Make sure the endpoint address matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with FCM - https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes).

I managed to make it work after login by getting the `deviceToken` from `AsyncStorage`.

If you want to keep the `endpointId` and only update the `userId` (only one user is logged in at each time - remember you can send push notifications to a specific `userId` that can have multiple endpoints (devices, email, phone number)):

```
try {
  const deviceToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('push_token'+aws_exports.aws_mobile_analytics_app_id)
  if (deviceToken !== null) {
    console.log('device token from AsyncStorage', deviceToken)
    Analytics.updateEndpoint({
      optOut: 'NONE',
      channelType: 'GCM',
      userId: userId,
      address: deviceToken,
    })
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error retrieving device token from AsyncStorage', error)
}
```

OR, if you want to specify your own `endpointId` (this way you can have multiple users/endpoints in the same device):

```
try {
  const deviceToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('push_token'+aws_exports.aws_mobile_analytics_app_id)
  if (deviceToken !== null) {
    console.log('device token from AsyncStorage', deviceToken)
    Analytics.configure({
      disabled: false,
      AWSPinpoint: {
        appId: aws_exports.aws_mobile_analytics_app_id,
        region: aws_exports.aws_mobile_analytics_app_region,
        endpointId: endpointId,
        endpoint: {
          address: deviceToken,
          channelType: 'GCM',
          optOut: 'NONE',
          userId: userId
        }
      }
    })
    Analytics.updateEndpoint({
      optOut: 'NONE',
    })
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error retrieving device token from AsyncStorage', error)
}
```

---

First, check your debug messages using `window.LOG_LEVEL='DEBUG'`

Then, make sure Analytics is working! Configure the Analytics module before the Push Notification module (https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/push-notifications#configure-your-app). Do you have a call to `PushNotification.configure()`?

As far as I know, you need to have `PushNotification.onRegister()` called to get a valid active targetable endpoint.

Are you testing in a real device?

And what happens if you don't set the `endpointId` and `endpoint` attributes on your `amplifyConfig`? It should update your endpoint address with the `device token` on its own. You can later on update your endpoint with the user id `Analytics.updateEndpoint({optOut: 'NONE', UserId: 'xxx'})`

ps.: I was having a related issue and now is finally working, but I set up my backend with Amplify CLI so it may be slightly different

Comment: If I remove the following
    endpointId: '5551212',
       endpoint: { 
         address: 'userID',
         channelType: 'GCM',
         optOut: 'NONE'
     }

It registers the Device ID and I can send to it, but I can't specify the endpointId in the updateEndpoint function call.

Comment: Oh, and to answer your other questions, I am calling PushNotification.configure(), and yes I'm testing with a real device.

My struggle is that I want to send to an endpoint ID, or some other identifier instead of a device ID, as we'll have multiple users on a device.

Comment: hey @PatrickDench I improved my answer, can you check if it helps you now?

Comment: I'll take a look - I hacked a work around using a RN module for the time being.  Pretty nasty, but...